# Mysql, How to custimize timestemp while selecting data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

Please I have a field `date` type timestamp (format 2013-03-29 14:32:34).

I want to select data from the table and group them by the field `date` but without time, I mean only by the format **Y-m-d**.

So I've tried :

```
SELECT date (Y-m-d) FROM table GROUP BY date (Y-m-d)
```

This return false. Please How could I do ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried? StackOverflow is not a drive-through code generator for the ignorant and lazy.

Comment: This question should not have any upvotes. It does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the date part of the datetime, use [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
SELECT DATE(date) FROM ...
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```